# Strange exception is thrown when the Spring data method is called

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Data method in my

```
@Repository
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Child> { ...
...
Optional<Child> findByUser(User user);

@Query("select child from Child child left join fetch child.kindergartenclasses where child.user =:user")
Optional<Child> findByUserWithEagerRelationships(User user);
```

Everything is good at compile time, while in the runtume I got the exception like those:

```
2019-09-12 11:52:29.981  WARN 8 --- [ XNIO-1 task-15] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.]
```

and before the conslode output has the full stack:

```
mental-app_1            | org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:370)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
mental-app_1            |   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.findByUserWithEagerRelationships(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.ChildBusinesslogicService.findChildForCurrentUser(ChildBusinesslogicService.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.ChildBusinesslogicService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8f4111d7.invoke(<generated>)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.ChildBusinesslogicService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1dd6a7d2.findChildForCurrentUser(<generated>)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.web.rest.ChildBusinesslogicResource.getChildForCurrentUser(ChildBusinesslogicResource.java:56)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
mental-app_1            |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
mental-app_1            |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.NormalStrategy.doFilter(NormalStrategy.java:41)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.SecurityStrategy.doFilter(SecurityStrategy.java:33)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$BasicQueryParameterSetterFactory.lambda$getName$3(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:252)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$BasicQueryParameterSetterFactory.getName(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:252)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$BasicQueryParameterSetterFactory.lambda$findParameterForBinding$2(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:243)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$BasicQueryParameterSetterFactory.findParameterForBinding(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:244)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$BasicQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:216)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createQueryParameterSetter$1(ParameterBinderFactory.java:139)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:141)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createSetters$0(ParameterBinderFactory.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:132)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryAwareBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:103)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.createBinder(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:103)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:93)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
mental-app_1            |   ... 144 common frames omitted
```

Is it because of Spring Data method contains parameter associated with the real entity fields, and the method name isn't ignored when having a `@Query` above it?

UPD:
changing the method name which don't have entity field mentions like `...ByUser...` still doesn't help, the same error.

```
...
Optional<Child> findOneWithEagerRelationships(User user);
```

Comment: The exception clearly tells you what to do. -> **For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.**.

Comment: so what is exactly a named parameter in my example? I have no undestanding what is exactly needed? just to place @Param before the User user or what?

Comment: In your quer `:user` is a named parameter. By default it will take the name of the method paramater to match the named parameter to the method argument, HOWEVER when compiling those are removed. Either compile with `-parameters` or add an `@Param("user")` to the `User` argument. That is also what the exception message is quite clearly telling you.

Comment: Please post as the question anwser. The only thing I can't agree is that the message is clear, at least not for me :)

Comment: If it isn't clear you aren't undertanding (part of) the technologies you are using.

Comment: sure, that's why I'm asking it there

Comment: so for me was unclear while it ever makes the compilation possible without this parameter annotation

Comment: Because at runtime named paramters aren't checked. Those are resolved at runtime when actually executing the query.

Comment: would you like to post the full answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query("select child from Child child left join fetch child.kindergartenclasses where child.user =:user")
Optional<Child> findByUserWithEagerRelationships(@Param("user") User user);
```

that is a required code, thanks to M. Deinum's answer. All I was missing here is `@Param("user")`